# How to add post via ajax, to loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i have home page, which render all posts

```
= render 'posts/post'
```

> welcome_controller.rb

```
    def home
    @user = User.all
    if user_signed_in?
      @posts = current_user.posts.all.page(params[:page]).per(25)
      @post = current_user.posts.build
    else
      hello
    end
  end
```

> and _post.html.haml

```
= div_for(@posts.each) do |p| 
  .content-wrap
    %hr
    %small= "Отправлено #{p.user.first_name} #{p.user.last_name}"
    = image_tag(p.user.img_url, class: 'img-responsive thumbnail user-image-home')
    %p.text-content= p.content
    %small.text-muted= "Добавлено #{time_ago_in_words(p.created_at)} назад"
    %br
    - if user_signed_in?
      = link_to "Удалить", p, method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Удалить?', 'confirm-button-text' => 'Удалить', 'cancel-button-text' => 'Нет', 'sweet-alert-type' => 'warning' }, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', id: 'wow' if current_user.id == p.user_id
    %hr
= paginate @posts
```

> and create.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>").appendTo(".content-wrap");
```

But it didnt work, in console i have a error like "undefined method each", i have no idea how to add a post, and i need to add it with all divs and styles to posts loop, not only text. Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think for starters `user_signed_in?` is not returning true so `@posts` is `nil`. Try this to make sure `@posts` is always defined, it will be populated when your conditional is true.

```
def home
  @user = User.all
  @posts = []
   if user_signed_in?
     @posts = current_user.posts.all.page(params[:page]).per(25)
     @post = current_user.posts.build
   else
     hello
   end
end
```

There is a lot of unconventional code here, I'd recommend wizzing through this tutorial: http://railsforzombies.org/